# Are these webrequests actually concurrent?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, webrequest

I have a `UrlList` of only 4 URLs which I want to use to make 4 concurrent requests. Does the code below truly make 4 requests which start at the same time?

My testing appears to show that it does, but am I correct in thinking that there will actually be 4 requests retrieving data from the URL target at the same time or does it just appear that way?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = Do_TaskWhenAll();
        t.Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Do_TaskWhenAll()
    {
        var downloadTasksQuery = from url in UrlList select Run(url);

        var downloadTasks = downloadTasksQuery.ToArray();

        Results = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
    }

    public static async Task<string> Run(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        AddHeaders(client);

        var content = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Depends on your definition of "at the same time"

Comment: Not in series. Aka, the traditional meaning.

Comment: They will always start at different time but they do not wait for the previous to finish to do so. Aka if you launch 4 of them that take 10 seconds each it should take 10-11 seconds to complete, not 40.

Comment: Ok, these are very long running API requests. I'm not concerned about a few milliseconds here or there between their starting time. But given that they will take >20 seconds to execute I want to be sure that they actually are (assuming the machine has the threads and connections available.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, when `ToArray` is called, the enumerable `downloadTasksQuery` will yield a task for every URL, running your web requests concurrently.

`await Task.WhenAll` ensures your task completes only when all web requests have completed.

You can rewrite your code to be less verbose, while doing effectively the same, like so:

```
public static async Task Do_TaskWhenAll()
{
    var downloadTasks = from url in UrlList select Run(url);

    Results = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
}
```

There's no need for `ToArray` because `Task.WhenAll` will enumerate your enumerable for you.

I advice you to use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`. Using `HttpClient`, you won't have to create a new instance of the client for each concurrent request, as it allows you to reuse the same client for doing multiple requests, concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes: if you generate multiple Tasks without awaiting each one individually, they can run simultaneously, as long as they are truly asynchronous.

When `DownloadStringTaskAsync` is awaited, a `Task` is returned from your `Run` method, allowing the next iteration to occur whilst waiting for the response.

So the next HTTP request is allowed to be sent without waiting for the first to complete.

As an aside, your method can be written more concisely:

```
public static async Task Do_TaskWhenAll()
{
    Results = await Task.WhenAll(UrlList.Select(Run));
}
```

`Task.WhenAll` has an overload that accepts `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` which is returned from `UrlList.Select(Run)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no guarantee that your requests will be executed in parallel, or immediately.

[Starting a task merely queues it to the thread pool.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/the-managed-thread-pool#maximum-number-of-thread-pool-threads) If all of the pool's threads are occupied, that task will necessarily wait until a thread frees up.

In your case, since there are a relatively large number of threads available in the pool, and you are queueing only a small number of items, the pool has no problem servicing them as they come in. The more tasks you queue at once, the more likely this is to change.

If you truly need concurrency, you need to be aware of what the thread pool size is, and how busy it is. [The `ThreadPool` class will help you to manage this.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: This is interesting in that I understand the nuance but that you are contradicting the post by @Rudey (he says yes, you say no). I'm not concerned about the thread pool having too few threads available, only that if the threads are available that the requests to the URLs actually run at the same time. In parallel. Concurrently. (Use whichever term makes you happy to get there.)

Comment: [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) when using truly asynchronous code. In fact a single thread could be used to fire off all 4 HTTP requests, as it will be released each time.